# How do I constantly query closest users?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, location, geofire

These functions are from two different service files. In my updateUserLocation I am continuously updating the current user's location and looking at the showClosestUser function in Location Service. I am trying to query with a radius of 100 right now (to test, ideally smaller like radius of 5 or 10). When I add breakpoints, I see updateUserLocation is continuously being called, but for the showClosestUser function the code runs up to "myQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with : { (key, location) in" and doesn't execute the "UserService.show(forUID: key, completion: { (user) in" code? I am trying to see if the user queried? (is that right) is not the current user so I can then I can do createNotification. Why isn't this code being executed?

```
static func updateUserLocation(location: CLLocation){
    var geoFireRef: DatabaseReference?
    var geoFire: GeoFire?

    geoFireRef = Database.database().reference().child("Geolocs")
    geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireRef!)
    geoFire?.setLocation(location, forKey:(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)

    LocationService.showClosestUser { (user) in
        if user != nil {
            UserService.createNotification()
        }
   }
}

static func showClosestUser( completion: @escaping (User) -> ()){
    var geoFireRef: DatabaseReference?
    var geoFire: GeoFire?
    var myQuery: GFQuery?

    geoFireRef = Database.database().reference().child("Geolocs")

    geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireRef!)

    let userLat = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "current_latitude") as! String
    let userLong = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "current_longitude") as! String

    let location:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(userLat)!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(userLong)!))

    myQuery = geoFire?.query(at: location, withRadius: 100)

    myQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with : { (key, location) in

        UserService.show(forUID: key, completion: { (user) in
            if let user = user {
                if (user.uid != User.current.uid){
                    completion(user)
                }
            }
            else {return}
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: If `UserService.show(` never gets called, the most logical conclusion is that there are not keys within the range you query.

Comment: There could be 100 things wrong - anything from the sequence not being called correctly to the userdefaults not being written correctly. Have you done any troubleshooting? Add a breakpoint to the code and step through it until something, like a variable, doesn't look right or some function isn't called? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)